# WHERE x IN works with a single value, not with multiple on json

Tags: mysql, where-clause, where-in, mysql-json

There's a hard to understand issue with querying on a json field in MySQL. The `data` column is of type json.

The following query works perfectly fine

```
SELECT * FROM `someTable` WHERE data->'$.someData' in ('A')
```

However the following one returns nothing.

```
 SELECT * FROM `someTable` WHERE data->'$.someData' in ('A','B')
```

Funnily enough this also works:

```
 SELECT * FROM `someTable` WHERE data->'$.someData'='A' OR data->'$.someData'='B'
```

I'm clueless as to why this happens. I originally thought that **WHERE x IN** executed in a json query format might be doing something like && but even if the values are ('A','A') it still returns nothing which essentially shows that more than one value in **WHERE x IN** wont work.

**SAMPLE DATA (any would do really)**

```
id | data (json)
1  | {"someData":"A"}
2  | {"someData":"B"}
```

Comment: Do you have any sample data demonstrating the problem?

Comment: any data would do. assume a table with only two columns, id and data where data is of type json. i added some on the question description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for a comment...

This seems to be related to an optimisation MySQL is performing when there is only one value in the `IN` expression (probably converting it to an `a = b` expression) and then it ignoring quotes. Strictly speaking,

```
SELECT * 
FROM `someTable` 
WHERE data->'$.someData' in ('A')
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM `someTable` 
WHERE data->'$.someData' = 'A'
```

should return no data because

```
SELECT data->'$.someData' 
FROM someTable;
```

returns

```
"A"
"B"
```

which is not the same as `A`. You need to use [`JSON_UNQUOTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) (or if you have MySQL 5.7.13 or later the [`->>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) operator) to get the actual value of the `someData` key:

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(data->'$.someData') FROm someTable;
SELECT data->>'$.someData' FROm someTable;
```

which gives

```
A
B
```

which then works fine with an `IN` expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `someTable` 
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(data->'$.someData') in ('A','B')
-- or use WHERE data->>'$.someData' in ('A','B')
```

Output:

```
id  data
1   {"someData":"A"}
2   {"someData":"B"}
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jFL45QAT34c7RSpZYRobXU/1)

Comment: MySQL also provides the `->>` operator which does the same thing -- unquotes a scalar value extracted by the JSON path.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the reminder. I've added notes about that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a join on a subquery instead of a IN clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM `someTable` s 
INNER JOIN (
   select 'A'  col
   union 
   select 'B'
 )  t ON t.col = s.data->'$.someData
```